# How to use jruby-complete programatically from Java?

Tags: java, jenkins, jruby

I've followed the following article http://seanchenxi.com/java/sass-compass-jruby-single-jar/ on how to get a jar with ruby, sass and compass.

I'd like to use this as part of a Jenkins plugin. Is there a way to call this programatically from Java the same way that you would run from the command line `java -jar jcompass.jar -S compass compile --help`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Warbler](https://github.com/jruby/warbler) can do that ... try packaging up with the **runnable** feature and see how it goes :

```
java -jar jcompass.jar -S compass compile
```

... even if it does not work please report with the project - should be "easily" fixable

Comment: I've tried with `warble runnable` and doesn't seem to be doing anything (or I'm not using it correctly as the documentation is kind of missing). With just `warble` in the folder where compass gem is installed it does seem to crete a jar file but it only bundles compass without its dependencies (sass and chunky_png)

Comment: first `warble config` than edit *config/warble.rb* (that should have been in the README) and there uncomment the `features` to include **runnable** ...